# Error al ejecutar comando flutter build apk

Tags: java, flutter, gradle, programación-móvil

Hola me encuentro arreglando un codigo que me pasaron. Sin embargo al intentar compilarlo o usar el camndo flutter build apk obtengo un error en consola. Actualmente estoy usando la version 1.22.4 de flutter para ejecutar este codigo ya que es algo viejo y en el archivo gradle-wrapper.properties he cambiado el  valor de la variable distributionUrl que antes era "https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.6.2-all.zip" por "...gradle-6.7-all.zip" ya que originalmente me marcaba este error:
**Could not initialize class org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper flutter**.

Este es el error que actualmente tengo en consola:

**FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
[   +1 ms] * What went wrong:
[        ] Could not open settings generic class cache for settings file 'C:\Users\Developer\Desktop\projectname\projectname\android\settings.gradle'

(C:\Users\Developer.gradle\caches\6.7\scripts\1fnwrr8g4rohfp291nvlxj5qe).
[        ] > BUG! exception in phase 'semantic analysis' in source unit '*BuildScript*' Unsupported class file major version 61**

He investigado un poco y parece ser un problema referente a la version de java de mi pc que es la 17 sin embargo si intento actualizar la variable distributioUrl a 7.3 que es la que soporta este java obtengo el siguiente error:

````
[        ]   - In plugin 'FlutterPlugin' type 'FlutterTask' property 'assets' is missing an input or output annotation.
[        ]     Reason: A property without annotation isn't considered during up-to-date checking.```
````

Comment: Mejor utiliza java 8 o java 11, en lugar de tocar las dependencias del proyecto